# firstorcreate is not working for new entry laravel

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5, ardent

I am new to laravel and using ardent for creating models, I have below base class for all model.

```
class MainModel extends Ardent {
  //with some common methods
}
```

and now i have sub model class such user

```
class User extends MainModel
{
  //with user table and other methods related to user
 }
```

and also I have repository for **user ->User Repository** and I am calling **firstOrcreate** method to check(user entry) and create user.
if user is exists in database then above method is working fine ,its returning existing user object but if user is not exists in database it is not creating user also its not inserting entry to table.is I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Does your log file give any insight into what the problem might be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to save the user after calling `firstOrCreate()`:

```
$user->save();
```

You may want to check if the user doesn't exist before that:

```
if (!$user->id)  $user->save();
```